# Angular file manager api ng6-file-man doesn't work

Tags: angular, file, npm

i've download the api, but i can't understand the system of parentpath. I try to use postman to call the api (https://github.com/Chiff/ng6-file-man-express),
but it does not work.
There is a "files" folder at the root is this where the root of the API starts? I put a filled folder in the file folder called "back".
[image]
[image]
I've been trying to make it work for 3 hours that I don't understand, can you help me?

Comment: hello, currently im quite busy with school and another project at work. also im working on updating FM and removing ngrx/store so we can work with AOT. I hope ill get back to you as soon as July 5th.

Comment: no problem thank you for creating this

Answer (score 1):

I found solution :

we need to remove the "/file" part, in the github example are : localhost:8080/api/file/download?parentPath=/folder1/someFile.txt

remove "/file/" to make this link :
localhost:8080/api/download?parentPath=/folder1/someFile.txt

and all it works, you should put the same links as in the github tutorial, people might not understand.

app.get('/api/list' to app.get('/api/file/list'